# Chart.js Pie Chart Dataset

Tags: chart.js

In my application, to the frontend it receives data as follows for the users by countries.

```
[
  {id: 10, name: 'USA', userCount: 100},
  {id: 20, name: 'UK', userCount: 200},
  {id: 30, name: 'SL', userCount: 300}
]
```

Now I want to set these data to datasets of my Pie Chart. I can get labels but there is a problem when setting the datasets. I want to set the userCount as the datasets. How can I do this?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.countryService.countriesWithUsers().subscribe(response => {
      response.map(r => {
        this.chart.labels.push(r.name);
        this.chart.datasets.push({data: r.userCount});
      });

      console.log(response);
      this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
        type: "pie",
        data: this.chart
      });
    });
  }
```